# How to setup an usbip server on ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: server

I am trying to setup an usbip server on ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x64.
I firstly installed the the following packages via the commands:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-generic
```

Then I load the modules via the command:

```
sudo modprobe usbip_core
sudo modprobe usbip_host
sudo modprobe vhci_hcd
```

Then I checked the running modules via command lsmod and grep, and I am sure all the three modules loaded successfully.
Finally, I got the error bellow when I was trying to list the local usb devices:

```
boliang@boliang-AO756:~$ sudo usbip list -l
[sudo] password for boliang: 
WARNING: usbip not found for kernel 5.15.0-43

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.15.0-43-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-43-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

I don't know if there are any errors in the above installation and configuration process, and if there are, what is the correct way. Thank you！

Comment: Please edit your question when providing additional information. The comments are our channel to ask for clarifications and give you transient information. The comments can be deleted when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Your question above says that you installed `linux-tools-generics`, which is the wrong name. Either install `linux-tools-generic` or fix your typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of exploration, I finally discovered the cause of the problem. There were two sets of usbip executable files in my system, one located under /usr/bin/ and the other under /usr/lib/linux-tools-x.x.x-xxx/. The former was installed by the linux-tools-common package, while the latter was installed by the linux-tools-x.x.x-xxx-generic package. As for why this happened, I am still not sure, but I feel that it may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to assign an IP address to a USB port, you don't need USBIP. Can be configured with ifconfig

```
sudo ifconfig usb0 172.32.0.100 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
```